# Office Word 2011 for Mac scrambles hyperlinks with different schemes

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office, url

I have a very urgent question.

I made my dad buy a MacBook Air just 3 days ago, I configured it completely and installed Microsoft Office 2011 for Mac, so far so good.

There is only one bad downside: Every Word document (.doc) which has hyperlinks with custom schemes (i.e: test://, whatever://) gets converted automatically to some weird file pointer scheme stuff. For example:

**Example 01:** "testing://onetwothree/" -> "file://localhost/testing/::onetwothree::"

**Example 02:** "one://two/" -> "file://localhost/one/::two::"

However, using "http://", "mailto://", "file://" **works with whatever you put after them**.

Typically, I'm looking for one simple solution: tell the Word not to validate the hyperlinks present on the document, whether the document is opened, saved, a hyperlink is created or edited, so they will not end up being converted/changed.

PS: This behavior is not present on Windows Office (any version), only on Mac Office 2011.

I have heard that Word Macros **CAN** overwrite the behavior for built-in function callbacks, something like VBA Scripts (correct me if I'm wrong).

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

As for the 'weird' file pointed scheme, that's just what Office '11 does with non-standard URLs. It is actually attempting to create a link to file on the computer's filesystem.

To have Word not create such links, in Word go to the **Preferences > AutoCorrect > AutoFormat as You Type** tab and un-check "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks".

Comment: I've had tried this already, but its not about "as you type, if its an hyperlink, create it". The problem here is specific to the URI Validation Callback that runs on Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac. I ended giving up and installed Office 2007 Enterprise Edition via CrossOver, working like a charm. Thank you!